# Handle emails sent from outlook in CRM 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have two kinds of received email on CRM: Email Router and Outlook.

When I use `(context.MessageName == "DeliverIncoming")` to get received emails, it works with those sent from EmailRouter but not those sent from Outlook.

Should I add a control?  How else can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide more information. Is this on a Create plugin on the Email entity?

Comment: The plugin is on "DeliverIncoming",

Comment: For more details: my code handle the data of  the received emails, to create new case. so my code work with emails sent from Email Router but not sent with Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the sent emails in the *Sent Items* folder in Outlook. To get the default delivery store Sent Items folder you can use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx) method of the Namespace class from the Outlook object model.

Also you can use the **Find**/**FindNext** or Restrict methods of the Items class to find the sent items in the folder. The **AdvancedSearch** method of the Application class allows to run the search in multiple folders asynchronously.

Comment: I need to create a plugin for CRM 2013

    Whenever an email is incomging I need to check if the email has the full data to create  a new  case record equivalent to this incoming mail.

    So my problem is how could i  get the  data of the emails sent from outlook to CRM users /contacts on my plugin. because i can  handle only the emails sent from Email Router .

Comment: The real need is   Create A Case And Send Confirmation Email  when we receive an email automaticlly on CRM from outlook.

Comment: Any feedback ?? some propositions please